# list of all the entry nodes

Tags: relays, guard-node

I need to know the list of all entry nodes. Is it possible to do this?
I found  here https://www.dan.me.uk/tornodes a list of all nodes or only exit nodes but I only need entry nodes.

Comment: `grep -B2 "^s.*Guard" /var/lib/tor/cached-microdesc-consensus | grep "^r" | awk '{print $6 ":" $7}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have them in that list, you only need to look at those with the "**G**uard" flag which specifies that they're entry nodes, for example:

> 4484.0298.4949.1082|ServerName|443|80|**G**FHRSDV|259492|Tor 0.2.9.10|

You'll only have to extract those with the **G** flag.

Comment: Thx man, But E flag = Exit node isnt it?.

Comment: According to the page it is: "NOTE: This is a FULL list including more than just exit nodes. If you only wish to block exit nodes you NEED to process the list to include only flags E and/or X!". It's probably the Gs (Guards) you want.

Answer (score 0):

https://atlas.torproject.org/#search/flag:Guard Here you can see also all nodes with the flag "Guard".

Answer (score 0):

As `NewUser` suggested, go to https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#search/flag:Guard, add your filters and with a quick network inspection, you will find out that there is a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) endpoint listing all the entries and it has filters too.

For example, to get all the running Exit nodes, we have

> https://onionoo.torproject.org/details?search=flag:Exit%20running:true

to get all the running Guard nodes, we have

> https://onionoo.torproject.org/details?search=flag:Guard%20running:true