# Automated way to fetch Tor guard IPs?

Tags: guard-node, torproject.org

Is there a way to fetch all the Tor guard IPs from the Tor Project website? I looked for an API but could not see. The information is actually public, but I cannot nicely fetch it, only see it in the Relay Search table.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

- Programatically using an API like [Stem](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/mirror_mirror_on_the_wall.html) (Python)
- Tor's [metrics](https://metrics.torproject.org/collector.html) project (see [here](https://metrics.torproject.org/sources.html) for more)
- Have a look at previous questions, e.g. [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14697/list-of-all-the-entry-nodes).